# how to display routes programmatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to display the routes in a Rails view (pretty much like `Rails routes` does in Rails 5)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.map { |r| r.path.spec.to_s }
#=> "/users/:id(.:format)"
```

If you want to get routes in the form they appear in console when you run `rails routes`:

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.map(&:name).compact.map { |route| "#{route}_path" }
#=> user_path
```